# Jailbroken lockscreen crash

Tags: ios, ipod-touch, jailbreak

I have the iPod touch 4th generation running jailbroken iOS 6.1.6.

The iPod is working fine except for when I lock it. When I try to wake it back up again, it doesn't come on. If I leave it for like a minute after trying to turn it on, it restarts the whole iPod for some reason.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Boot into Safe Mode by holding the volume up button on boot. If the problem doesn't occur in Safe Mode, it's a substrate tweak causing the problem. Still in Safe Mode, go to Cydia and uninstall any lock screen related tweaks until the problem is fixed.